# Google Chrome not recognizing greater than 3 digit amount in .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, digits

We have a .NET MVC application that is developed to approve payment requests. When the approval amount is greater than 3 digits > $999.00 the Approve button does not work in Chrome but it works fine in IE. Example if approval amount is $999 the button works if it is $1000 or more the button does not work. Please suggest why there is different behavior in Chrome and how to fix it.

Comment: Showing your code will help a lot.

Comment: We will need to see the front end and backend code for this button, as well as any validation code that is involved. Have you tried checking for console errors using the Chrome developers tools, or seeing that the network request is actually being sent (also via developer tools), or putting a breakpoint in your controller method to see if it is actually being hit. We need to know what you have already tried so that we can better answer your question.